# Preamplifier vs. Pulser Input

Tags: experimental-physics, nuclear-physics, experimental-technique

I'm using a Mesytec MPR-16-LOG preamplifier for some testing of gas ionization chamber. It has a 25 pin D connector input, in addition to an input labelled "Pulser In", that is a lemo connector input. I've never heard of a pulser input, what's it all about?

http://www.mesytec.com/products/nuclear-physics/MPR-16-log.html

Comment: If you are working in a well supplied lab (as opposed to doing a home project), you can probably just ask a colleague to show you the pulsers that are used in the lab. The ones I've used in the past are black plastic boxes about 2.5 cm square by 1 cm thick with a lemo port on one of the small sides. They only pulse when plugged in, and the 2032 coin battery inside that can run it continuously for upwards of a month.

Answer (score 1):

A pulser is a (usually off the shelf and sometimes battery driven) electronic debugging tool that emits a steady stream of pulses.

The typical pulser emits one pulse per second in the logic format most often used with the physical layer cabling it couples to.

You use them for several purposes

- To check the functioning of lines and components of triggers and similar electronics. By observing the pulse before and after some portion of the trigger in an oscilloscope you can see if the edges are being degraded; if reflections are occurring in the part of the system you are testing; and measure that the timing delays actually occurring are those you allowed for in the trigger design.
- To [select an unbiased sample](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32040/520) of events. By triggering on the output of a pulser one gets a sample of the data coming into a detector that it not biased by decisions made in designing the usual trigger logic. This allows the measurement of efficiencies and tests to insure that important data is not being lost.
- As a means of measuring deadtime. The fraction of pulser pulses that actually generate a trigger is the livetime. If you need high precision, you generally use a separate scaler to count the pulses rather than counting on the pulser clock to be precise. (Hat tip: [john](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/154816/john) in the comments.)
- As a means of evaluating and standardizing the gain in application such as multi-channel analyzers. (Hat tip: [Jon Custer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/38675/jon-custer) in the comments.)

In your case I imagine it is there so that you can measure the gain and the amplification delay.

Comment: They also are used to provide a consistent marker for, e.g. multichannel analyzer spectra.

Comment: @Jon That's not an application I have any experience with—we always normalized gain with known sources—so I find myself wondering how stable the charge per pulse really is. In particular is it stable in temperature and does it sag when the cell in a battery powered pulser nears the end of its life?

Comment: The ones I used where Nimbin modules, so pretty stable.

Comment: Yes. That's a very different thing than the hand-help, battery operated ones I'm used to.

Comment: The battery powered ones (e.g. Phillips Scientific 417 Pocket Pulser) do seem to be a different beast than something like the Ortec 419 NIM Precision Pulse Generator or even the simpler Ortec 480 Pulser. Sigh. Few recent graduates know much about NIM modules and how powerful they are.

Comment: It does seem a shame to me that there is no current, common hardware standard for modular DAQ components. NIM is desperately underpowered by modern standards and simply antique and CAMAC and VME are expensive *and* none-the-less out-dated. At conferences I see reps pushing their company's nifty modular toys, but none of them inter-operate. NIM had a useful run of over two decades despite Moore's law in part because you could mix and match components from multiple suppliers (plus a thumb-fingered graduate student could solder boards for the commodious slots).